# What is the equivalent of Swift 3.0 withUnsafeMutableBytes in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift2

Can anyone help me porting this piece of code from 3.0 to Swift 2.2 or or Objective-C?

`// start building the ASN.1 header`

```
let headerBuffer = headerData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
(bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer) -> UnsafeMutablePointer in
// sequence start
bytes[0] = kCryptoExportImportManagerASNHeaderSequenceMark
return bytes
}
```

I'm porting a library for RSA encryption from swift 3.0 to 2.2. I stuck at withUnsafeMutableByte. Swift 2.2 doesn't support this method.

Thank you

Comment: Consider to update **your** code to Swift 3. That's the future.

Comment: This is Swift 3 code and doesn't require an update. However I,m downgrading from Swift 3.0 to 2.2 for valid reasons.

Comment: I mean consider not to downgrade. What are the *valid reasons*?

Comment: As told there is reasons to downgrade. My long running project is started when Swift 3 was in Beta. Now after number of sprints already gone we can't afford and upgrade unless we have couple of weeks in hand.